# Zapier: See outgoing POST'd data in curl form

Tags: zapier, coda, lowcode

A colleague is trying to create a no/low code flow that posts data from Zapier to Coda. Coda is receiving empty packets, and it's hard to debug why.

Is it possible in Zapier to see outgoing POST requests in cURL form? That will make it crystal clear what is being sent over the wire.